# Is there any way to create Robot file with multiple Test Templates in robot framework?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework, testautomationfx

I would like to know if there is anyway to create multiple Test Temapltes in single robot file.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template    Login with invalid credentials should fail
Test Template    Open Browser


*** Test Cases ***                USERNAME         PASSWORD
Invalid User Name                 invalid          ${VALID PASSWORD}
Invalid Password                  ${VALID USER}    invalid

Chrome                            ${URL1}
Chrome                            ${URL2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use test templates in test cases, which will turn them into this data-driven approach.

Example would be:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    [Template]    ${first} plus ${second} equals ${expected}
    1    1    2
    1    2    3

Test Case 2
    [Template]    ${first} minus ${second} equals ${expected}
    1    1    0
    5    2    3
```

You should also read [Test Templates section](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates) in the official documentation.

Comment: Agreed, i would like consider each data set to be 1 test case. like above i need to generate report with 4 test cases passed where as now generate only 2 test cases.